# PDOException in Connector.php line 119: could not find driver

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, centos

I installed Laravel 5.3 on CentOS 6.8. I updated php to 5.6.27, installed mysql-pdo, php-pdo.

> In phpinfo(): PDO drivers: sqllite SQLite Library 3.6.20

But when I get data from DTB, I still get error:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 119: could not find driver.

I did some search online, and one of solutions is:

> uncommented ;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll,

but I can't find it in my ect/php.ini file. when I add it manually, I got the message "

> php startup unable to load dynamic library php_pdo_mysql.dll ...

" in php artisan migrate, and the error display in web is still the same.
Here's my env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:*somekey*
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydtb
DB_USERNAME=myusername
DB_PASSWORD=mypass

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

My website address is 192.168.1.100 in local.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: why's it using dll on Centos? Should be .so

Comment: I add extension=pdo.so and extension=pdo_sqlite.so to php.ini, but it's still not work

Comment: In your php.ini what is the location of extension_dir

Comment: Run 'whereis php' it should give you the location of your php.ini file

Comment: Mine on centos is /usr/lib/php.ini

Comment: you need to install pdo_mysql.so in centos .dll extension is for windows os not linux and generally pdo comes preinstalled with php check here about how to install php https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-6

Comment: I installed both mysql-pdo and php-pdo. and they are all active, but the error is still.
In phpinfo(): Additional .ini files parsed has /etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini,  /etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
But PDO drivers just have sqllite, how to enable mysql?